How to use Xcode's Main Thread Checker?
How to detect using Xcode all areas in the codebase where UI is updated.
I want It causes the app to become unresponsive
I want to enable these purple warnings
"This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to Ul unresponsiveness."
I have already enabled Main Thread Checker in Edit Scheme -> Run -> Diagnostics -> Runtime API Checking But I dont get these warnings as shown in the image attached



You are not getting warnings because you are not updating the interface on a background thread. So don't worry, be happy. Actually, if you did update the interface on a background thread, you would probably get more than a warning — the main thread checker would probably crash you.

These are shown on runtime. Meaning that if you call the UI method from two different spots, one from background, one from main thread, if when testing you call only from mainthread, you won't have the run time error...

@matt They appear sometimes, I am quite sure there are lot of areas in the codebase where background thread is updating UI

There are many sources of unresponsiveness in the UI. And the Xcode diagnostic options shown in the question are not the only resources we have:
I would suggest you consider using the Instruments’ “Time Profiler” template, which includes the “Hangs” tool. See WWDC 2023’s video Analyze hangs with Instruments, 2022’s Track down hangs with Xcode and on-device detection, and 2021’s Understand and eliminate hangs from your app.

For example, I deliberately manifested a hang by compressing and decompressing a large asset using the Compression framework on the main thread. (What I did to manifest the hang is not terribly relevant. This is just a random example of something that will block the calling thread.)
The Xcode diagnostics did not identify the problem; those diagnostics only report very specific sorts of issues. But, when I profiled it in Instruments, the “Hangs” tool identified this as a “microhang”. I then control-clicked on the hang “interval” and chose “Set the inspection range” from the context menu. Having narrowed my analysis to just the time during which the hang took place, I then jumped over to the “Time Profiler” tool and see what the app was doing when it hung:

I can even double-click on the symbol in the stack trace, and Instruments will take me to the offending code:

As an aside, I sometimes find the “Record Waiting Threads” recording option for “Time Profiler” tool in Instruments to be helpful in these cases, too. It ensures we capture performance samples even while a thread is waiting for another:

You can even configure the “Hangs” tool to specify what sort of hangs you want to detect:

Bottom line, I would suggest watching a few of those videos and you will better understand the diverse array of issues that can affect app responsiveness, as well as how to use these tools to identify and diagnose the issues.
